# How do I get Slim Framework to work without having to put /index.php in the URL?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, slim

I am implementing Slim Framework for PHP and everything appears to be working just fine. However, the only way I can get it to work is by putting /index.php in the URL like this:

> `http://www.example.com/index.php/members/1`

I want it to work like this:

> `http://www.example.com/members/1`

I have a feeling it has something to do with my .htaccess but I'm not sure. Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ . [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Having the same problem... I can get the / to reroute to index.php but any subdirs are not being rerouted...

Answer (score 5):

Restoring the commented (`#`) line and getting rid of the other one should help. When you downloaded Slim Framework, it [originally had this in the .htaccess](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim/blob/master/.htaccess) as well.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [QSA,L]
```

Also, you should [learn about writing rewrite rules](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/), because you won't get far without it.

Comment: Thanks, @bazmegakapa. That is what I originally had in my .htaccess but it still doesn't seem to work. I have a feeling my Rewrite Engine might not be on. I am trying to tshoot this right now.

Answer (score 4):

I think this answer comes late, but following the information of this link http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/
What I needed was to add the **AllowOverride All** statement to my virtual host configuration, and that worked for me.

Comment: Didn't come late at all, it helped me... i totally forgot to configure that feature in my new server ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtual host and allowOverRide all.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ /index.php [QSA,L]
```